# Transaction accept null, and don't rollback

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I'll try to be so specific.

I'm reading a CSV file into `DataGridView`, the user can see the information if the user validates the information, he sends to an SQL Server database.

[image]

I'm using a stored procedure transaction with parameters to send the information.

Called from Visual Studio:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CadenaConexionBD.cs)) {
    conn.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < dgvTrabajadores.Rows.Count - 1; i++){
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SistemaFAIFAP.cargaTransTrabajadores", conn)){
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            string stringGuid = guid.ToString();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", stringGuid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ap", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["APELLIDOPATERNO"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@am", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["APELLIDOMATERNO"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["NOMBRE"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", DateTime.Parse(dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["FECHANACIMIENTO"].Value.ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pn", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["PAISNACIMIENTO"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@en", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["ENTIDADNACIMIENTO"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nn", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["NombreNacionalidad"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nss", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["NSS"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfc", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["RFC"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hom", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["HOMONIMIA"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@curp", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["CURP"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ec", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["ESTADOCIVIL"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["SEXO"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ce", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["CORREOELECTRONICO"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["CATEGORIA"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dc", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["DESCRIPCIONCATEGORIA"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@calle", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["CALLE"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["NUMEROEXTERIOR"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["COLONIA"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mun", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["MUNICIPIO"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ent", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["ENTIDAD"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["TELEFONO"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dep", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["DEPENDENCIA"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subdep", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["SUBDEPENDENCIA"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dir", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["DIRECCION"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depa", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["DEPARTAMENTO"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ofi", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["OFICINA"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@npl", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["NUMEROPLAZA"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cvep", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["CLAVEPROGRAMATICA"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fig", DateTime.Parse(dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["FECHAINGRESOGOBIERNO"].Value.ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nc", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["NUMEROCONTROL"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cvee", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["CLAVEEMPLEADO"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ior", dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["IDOFICINARECAUDADORA"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fum", DateTime.Parse(dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["FECULTMOV"].Value.ToString()));

            filasAfectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    if (filasAfectadas <= 0){
        MessageBox.Show("Los datos no se cargaron de manera correcta. \nContacte al Administrador del Sistema.", "Error al cargar la base de datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        conn.Close();
    }else{
        MessageBox.Show("Se cargó correctamente la información", "Datos agregados", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        validacion = 1;
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

My store in the database:

**SECOND EDITION TO A DevCod SOLUTION**

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [SistemaFAIFAP].cargaTransTrabajadores 
@id uniqueidentifier, @ap NVARCHAR (64), @am NVARCHAR (64), @n NVARCHAR (64) = NULL,
@fn DATE, @pn NVARCHAR (50), @en NVARCHAR (50), @nn NVARCHAR (50),
 @nss NVARCHAR (11), @rfc NVARCHAR (10), @hom NVARCHAR (3), @curp NVARCHAR (18),
 @ec NVARCHAR (50), @sex NVARCHAR (50), @ce NVARCHAR (50), @cat NVARCHAR (6),
 @dc NVARCHAR (64), @calle NVARCHAR (255), @num NVARCHAR (10), @col NVARCHAR (60),
 @mun NVARCHAR (50), @ent NVARCHAR (50), @tel NVARCHAR (10), @dep NVARCHAR (3),
 @subdep NVARCHAR (2), @dir NVARCHAR (3), @depa NVARCHAR (3), @ofi NVARCHAR (4),
 @npl NVARCHAR (4), @cvep NVARCHAR (6), @fig DATE, @nc NVARCHAR (64), @cvee NVARCHAR (64),
 @ior FLOAT, @fum 
DATE AS
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
IF(ISNULL(@n,'')='' OR @n = NULL OR @n = '')
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('@n is null or empty. This is not allowed. Insert will be    rollbacked',-- Message text to return to the UI.
       16, -- Severity.
       1 -- State
       )
END
INSERT INTO sistemaFAIFAP.TrabajadorBuffer
VALUES(
    @id,        @ap,        @am,        @n,     @fn,
    @pn,        @en,        @nn,        @nss,       @rfc,
    @hom,       @curp,      @ec,        @sex,       @ce,
    @cat,       @dc,        @calle,     @num,       @col,
    @mun,       @ent,       @tel,       @dep,       @subdep,
    @dir,       @depa,      @ofi,       @npl,       @cvep,
    @fig,       @nc,        @cvee,      @ior,       @fum
) 
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

As you can see in the pic, I put a `null` field as test.
I have my table defined as `Not Null` in field `Nombre`, but it doesn't show an error message, and the information is inserted in the table.

[image: asd]

How can I prevent sending empty records?

(It's my first time using transaction) Why doesn't my stored procedure show an error message and proceeds as if the field `Nombre` has a value?

Comment: Perhaps an empty string is being sent from your C# code. In your stored proc try adding `NULLIF(@n, '')` in the values.

Comment: Well, that works but now that record is omitted, even as error. I'm trying to send 102 registries but only loads 101.

Comment: `As you can see in the pic, I put a null field as test` - no, I cannot see that from the pic. I can see from the code that you pass `dgvTrabajadores.Rows[i].Cells["NOMBRE"].Value.ToString()` for `@n`. That is not going to be `null`.

Comment: I don't know what should I say, guess... thank you? You help a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. First of all, dgvTrabajadores.Rows.Count Should not contain data that cannot be saved. Add UI validation to the Grid using Javascript, .net validators. Prompt the User, "Column cannot be null".
2. Place one try catch just for the "for loop". In catch block, consolidate all error message in string format and display it at the end.

Ex;

```
string ErrorMsg = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dgvTrabajadores.Rows.Count - 1; i++){
try
{
  cmd.SavingOneRowAtOneTime()
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  //Example, change it as you need.
  ErrorMsg += (ErrorMsg == "") ?  "Insert failed for Rows: " + i.ToString() : "," + i.ToString();
}
}
//At the end
if(ErrorMsg != "")
 MessageBox.Show(ErrorMsg);
}
```

Please mark this as answer, if it is an acceptable answer for you. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Sounds good, validate from Interface and don't let the user upload a database if contains a blank space in some columns. Thanks for the idea, i'll implements this and i'll show you. I'll mark as answer when i've made the changes. And sorry i only have 7 reputation to remove this "-1".

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the parameters on the SQL Side to check if they are null or blank. In that case you can raise the error from the procedure and rollback transaction. You can use RAISERROR for custom error message, refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

```
Create table Trabajador_TEST(n NVARCHAR (64) not null)
Go
CREATE PROCEDURE cargaTransTrabajadores_TEST
(@n NVARCHAR (64) = null)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
-- Place any number of Condition that you do not want to allow.
IF(ISNULL(@n,'')='')
Begin
RAISERROR ('@n is null or empty. This is not allowed. Insert will be rollbacked',-- Message text to return to the UI.
           16, -- Severity.
           1 -- State
           )
End

INSERT INTO Trabajador_TEST VALUES(@n) 
-- All Set, Save It.
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  -- Something Wrong so Do not Save It.

SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; --Return the error message back to the UI.
END CATCH
END
```

Exec cargaTransTrabajadores_TEST null

This insert data should not work. It Should raise error back to UI.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the delay in my answer, i tried new things with your idea, but i receive a new error in a SqlException. I edit my sql code to show what i did.

**The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION**

Any solution?

Comment: You got the RAISERROR at the wrong spot. It should be after BEGIN TRANSACTION statement, so when the BEGIN CATCH is called due to the RAISERROR it has a Transaction to rollback. BTW: In case you handle the UI code, a validation prompt " 'UI Element of @N' is Empty, Please specify a value!" would avoid tackling these issues at the SQL Side.

Comment: Actually it runs and don't show any error... only omits the blank registry. I update my query, and I added a few "OR's" but, nope.